# Writing to file fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to write an NSMutableArray to a file, however it fails every single time. I believe that the path I have stated is correct. What else could be the problem?

```
for (int i=1; i<=10/*[self getcurrentnumber]*/;i++)
{
    [mutablearray addObject:[self convertJSONtoDictionary:[self generateJSONforcomic:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]]]];
    NSLog(@"Iteration %i",i);
}
NSLog(@"Done %.0u",[mutablearray count]);

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *location = [libraryDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/Comics.txt"];
NSLog(location);
[mutablearray writeToFile:location atomically:YES];
if(![mutablearray writeToFile:location atomically:YES])NSLog(@"Fail");
```

I'm using introspection to ensure that convertJSONtoDictionary actually returns a dictionary.

Comment: why are you writing the same array twice? And check whether your mutablearray is not nil.

Comment: Wow! I'm kind of embarrassed right now ... It was indeed nil. Thanks Max! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have some kind of object in the array that it cannot write out into a plist (which is by default the storage mechanism for an array).

Common examples would be any custom class, a UIImage, or NSNull (since you have JSON you are parsing).

If you cannot make a plist by hand that has what you are trying to save out then the array cannot write it either.

Comment: No, it was a much simpler problem: My array was nil :/ Sorry to have wasted your time!

Comment: Aha. No worries, some day when someone else has an array that is not writing to disk my answer may help them...